# Set-theoretic foundations for formal language theory?

Tags: set-theory

Has anyone ever seen any papers or books including set-theoretic descriptions of formal language theory? Specifically, I'm interested in how one would formalize context-free grammars with sets.

Some of this, I suppose is fairly obvious. For example, strings would use a foundational formalism much like ordered pairs (e.g.  Kuratowski's definition or similar) but what about objects like production rules and their semantics?

This isn't really necessary for me to get any actual work done, I just thought it would help me build a better intuition around formal language theory.

Thanks in advance,

- Anthony

Update:

An example of what I'm looking for would be string concatenation. How would one construct this in pure set theroy? If we consider the strings "a" and "b", and consider their set representations to be { { a } } and { { b }} (as per Kuratowski), then the desired result would be { { a }, { a, b } }. Clearly this cannot be accomplished by a defining string concatenation to be set union but there are obviously numerous ways of doing so. The choice at each point in defining how to do something in formal language theory using pure set theory will, in some cases, determine how other notions can be defined. As a consequence, some definitions may be more complex than others (or less elegant than others, one might say). I'm just curious if anyone has done anything like this before.

Comment: Isn't this bound to be circular?  I mean, don't we need a formal language in the first place to define set theory?

Comment: Certainly it would be circular to a degree, however one could minimize the amount of required symbols. For example, if it could be done just with a minimal set of set-theoretic symbols, then it may provide some interesting insight.

Comment: What's not set-theoretic about production rules?  Take the set of all trees that can be formed by repeated use of the production rules and add to your formal language the set of all words that result from such trees.  Both of these things are perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: It seems to me that what you're proposing is a way of generating an entire (potentially infinite) language from a grammar. I also did not ask whether or not these descriptions existed, just where I could find them. Let me update the question with a more concrete example of what I'm asking.

Comment: You can define words as maps from finite ordinals to your alphabet (which is precisely what they are!), and concatenation as the obvious map from the ordinal sum... You seem to making waves in a cup of tea :P

Comment: Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: I agree. It's trivial, but I'm still curious. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Making waves in a cup of tea?  That's the first time I've ever heard that expression before.. But I like it.

Comment: There is a certain degree of circularity, but only on the surface. This is because no formal language can reason or express itself with any meaning. For example, as soon as you try to collect all the codes for true statements about a particular universe, you have just stepped up the consistency strength of the system you are working in. A related construction is called $0^{\sharp}$, and a quick description of it is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp . (Of course I'm blurring the fine details a bit, but this is the gist.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can do this using less technology, too...

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet, $N$ a set of non-terminals, and $\Sigma^\*$ and $(\Sigma\cup N)^\*$ the full languages on $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma\cup N$, respectively. A context-free grammar is a finite subset $G\subset N\times(\Sigma\cup N)^\*$. Given one such grammar $G$ there is a relation $\mathord\rightarrow_G\subseteq(\Sigma\cup N)^\*\times(\Sigma\cup N)^\*$ which is the least transitive reflexive relation which contains $G$ (notice that $N\times(\Sigma\cup N)^\*\subseteq (\Sigma\cup N)^\*\times(\Sigma\cup N)^\*$, so this makes sense) and such that
$$a\rightarrow_Gb \wedge a'\rightarrow_Gb'\implies ab\rightarrow_Ga'b'.$$ The language generated by $G$ from a non-terminal $n\in N$ is just $L(G, n)=\{w\in \Sigma^\*:n\rightarrow_Gw\}$. This is, in fact, the standard way to do this...

Comment: Actually, yes, this is much closer to what I had in mind. Beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

Hi Anthony,

The question you're asking in your text isn't quite the same as the question in your title, but the answer to the title subsumes the one you ask in the text.

To define a grammar, we start with a an alphabet $\Sigma$, and a set of nonterminal variable $N$, and then define a *grammatical expression* as an element of the formal semiring $G$ over $\Sigma + N$. (It's a good exercise to see how the semiring axioms let you convert grammatical expressions into their Backus normal form.) Next, a *grammar* is a map from $N \to G$ -- that is, it assigns a grammatical expression to each variable.

Now, consider the free monoid over $\Sigma$. Concretely, these are sequences of characters in $\Sigma$. A *language* is a set of these strings, and our goal is to give an interpretion sending nonterminals to languages. If we had a map $f$ sending nonterminals to languages, we could interpret grammatical expressions inductively, by interpreting the formal multiplication in the ring as concatenation (using the monoid operation) of elements in each language, and interpreting the formal sum as set union of languages.

Now, consider the free monoid over $\Sigma$. Concretely, these are sequences of characters in $\Sigma$. A *language* is a set of these strings (ie, an element of $\mathcal{P}(\Sigma^{*})$), and our goal is to give an interpretion sending nonterminals to languages. If we had a map $f$ sending nonterminals to languages, we could interpret grammatical expressions inductively, by interpreting the formal multiplication in the ring as concatenation (using the monoid operation) of elements in each language, and interpreting the formal sum as set union of languages.

If we have such an interpretation (a function $N \to \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^{*})$) and a grammar (a map $N \to G$), we can lift the grammar to an endofunction on interpretations -- that is, to a function $(N \to L) \to (N \to L)$. (I'm using $L$ for a set of strings due to jsMath flakiness -- it should be powerset-sigma-star.)

The language for each nonterminal will be the least fixed point of this functional. (As a technical detail, to make this functional monotone, so that the Knaster-Tarski theorem applies, you need to ensure that each interpretation also unions the new language with the old argument language -- ie, you take an interpretation $i$ sketched above and change it to $\lambda f.\;\lambda n.\; f(n) \cup i(n)$.)

I should also add that this is all standard material, which should appear in every textbook on formal language theory. (I'm pretty sure it's in Sipser.)

Comment: Very nice. That's definitely more along the lines of what I was thinking about, thank you. I think the end of your post was cut off though :\

Comment: Thanks again. I suppose that's what I get for self-education: I had started with a book on automata theory and another on compilers, but after seeing what you said and looking on Google books, it seems this is indeed part of many books on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

For the foundations of formal language theory, the following ideas show up:

1. Universal algebra (here for 'free' monoids and basic logic involving simple equation only proofs, just variables and no connectives or quantifiers)
2. Term rewriting systems (take a look at the wikipedia article)

As for foundations, I have found that much FOM (Foundations of Mathematics) is done assuming full blown ZFC set theory.  You can certainly think of formal language theory, computability theory, model theory, etc... as subjects in ZFC just like any other subject such as abstract algebra or topology/geometry.  There is no danger here as long as the context in which the results were derived is clear.

Meta-mathematical work is often done in ZFC first and then under weaker systems later.